# Log in system + news feed error

Tags: php, mysql, css, database

I'm creating a log in + news feed site. I've set up all the databases which are needed.

This is the code for all of the sites:

Index.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

 mysql_pconnect("MyServer","Username","Password");
  mysql_select_db("Database_Name");

  $page = $_GET['page'];

   ?>


   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>InstaWord</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>

    <body>
   <center>
   <table>
   <tr>
    <td id="body">

    <h1>News Feed <a href="?page=Home">Home</a></h1>




     <?php

    if ( !$page ) {

        $page = "Home";

    }

    include("$pages.php");

?>


      </td>
      <td id="nav">

      <?php

      if ( !$_SESSION['uid'] ) {

   ?> <a href="?page=Login">Login</a>

        <?php

     } else {

          ?>

          <a href="?page=Admin">Profile</a> | <a href="?page=Logout">Logout</a>

        <?php

   }

   ?>


   </td>
  </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The style.css looks like this:

```
body {

background: #cfcfcf;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 }

  td {

font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;

   }


    #body {

background: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #000;
width: 600px;
padding: 10px;


    }

    #nav {

background: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 10px;
width: 125px;
}
```

The Home.php looks like this:

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news1`") or die(mysql_error());

if ( mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0 ) {

   echo "There are no posts.";

} else {

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news1` ORDER BY `time` DESC") or    die(mysql_error());

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ) {

       echo "<hr>";

       echo "<h3>";

       echo $row['news_title'];

       echo "</h3>";

       echo $row['news_body'];



      }

      }

    ?>
```

The Login.php looks like this:

```
   <?php

   if ( !$_SESSION['uid'] ) {
   if ( !$_POST['submit'] ) {
   ?>  

   <form action="?page/Login"  method="post">
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>Username</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Password</td>
   <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
   </tr>
   <td colspan="2">
   <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submut">
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </form> 

   <?php       
   } else {

       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = md5($_POST['password']);

       $errors = array();

       if ( !$username ) {

           $errors[1] = "Please enter a username.";

        }

        if ( !$password ) {

            $errors[2] = "Please enter a password";

        }


       $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users3` WHERE `name`='$username'";

       $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

       $exists = mysql_num_rows($res);

       if ( $exists == 0 ) {

           $errors[3] = "The username does not exist!";

       } else {


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users3` WHERE `name`='$username' AND  `password`='$password'";

            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

            $exists = mysql_num_rows($res);

            if ( $exists == 0 ) {

                $errors[4] = "The username and password do not match.";

            }

     }


     if ( count($errors) > 0 ) {

         echo "<ul>";

         foreach ( $errors as $error ) {
             echo "<li>";
             echo $error;
             echo "</li>";
         }

         echo "</ul>

     } else {

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users3` WHERE `name`='$username' AND `password`='$password'";

          $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

          $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

          $_SESSION['uid'] = $res['user_id'];

          echo "You have successfully logged in! <a href=\"?  page=Home\">Home</a><br><br>";





     }


       }  else {

   echo "You are already logged in!";

   include("?pages/Home.php");

        }

       }
       }

       ?>
```

The Logout.php looks like this:

```
<?php

$_SESSION['uid'] = "";

?>
You have logged out!
```

And the Admin.php looks like this:

```
<?php

$action = $_GET['action'];

if ( !$action ) {
?>

<a href="?page=Admin&action=Post">Post News</a><br>
<a href="?page=Admin&action=Edit">Edit/Delete News</a><br>

<?php   
} else {

    if ( $action == "Post" ) {

    if ( !$_POST['submit'] ) {



    ?>

    <form action="?page=Admin&action=Post" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>News Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="news_title"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>News Body</td>
        <td><textarea name="news_body" cols="8" rows="4"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post News">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>


    <?php  

    } else {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
        $news_title = $_POST['news_title'];
        $news_body = $_POST['news_body'];
        $time = time();

        $errors = array();

        if ( !$user_id ) {

            $errors[1] = "You are not logged in.";

        }

        if ( !$news_title ) {

            $errors[2] = "Please enter a title of the news.";

        }

        if ( !$news_body ) {

            $errors[3] = "Please enter a news body.";

        }

        if ( count($errors) > 0 ) {

            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ( $errors as $error ) {

                echo "<li>";
                echo $error;
                echo "</li>";

            }

            echo "</ul>";

        } else {

           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `news1` (`news_id`, `news_title`, `news_body`, `user_id`, `time`) 
           VALUES ('$news_title', '$news_body', '$user_id', '$time');';") or die(mysql_error());

           echo "You have posted the news successfully!";

        }


    }

    } elseif ( $action == "Edit" ) {

        if ( !$_GET['id'] ) {



             $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news1`") or die(mysql_error());

             while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ) {

             echo $row['news_title'] . " | <a href=\"?page=Admin&action=Edit&id=" . $row['news_id'] . "&type=Delete\">Delete</a><br>";

        }

        } else {

            $type = $_GET['type'];

            $id = $_GET['id'];

            if ( $type == "Delete" ) {

                $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `news1` WHERE `news_id`='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
                echo "You successfully deleted the news entry.";

            }

        }

    }

}

    ?>
```

But try to go on http://www.youngcreativity.com

You can see the error on the first page: [image: Error]

On my server I've imported this files:

[image: Server]

Please, help me solve this problem. I've been stuck on it for a very long time...

Comment: `include("?pages/Home.php");` what do u mean by `?pages/Home.php` it may be `include("pages/Home.php");`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work with include("pages/Home.php");....

Comment: your problem is near `include("$pages.php");` what value given in `$pages` ? in index.php line 39

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but $page = $_GET['page']; ?

Comment: try `include("$page.php");` instead of `include("$pages.php");`

Comment: You really need just create github repository, so that you wouldn't need to put so much code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

in index.php line 39 is:

include("$pages.php");

is should be :

include("pages/$page.php");

This will fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, It solved it! But now, when I click on login I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /hsphere/local/home/surflida/youngcreativity.com/pages/Login.php on line 87

Comment: you need a "; at the end of line 83, and the else at line 101 it's wrong, remove it with the brackets.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. But now when I log in it works but I can't see the logout button... XD

Comment: But, it it should when you're logged in show a "Admin" page where you can post a news. But it just logg in, and there's nothing execpt it says "There are no post". Even if I log in with a wrong username and password it log in...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line 83

```
            echo "</ul>


             echo "</ul>";
```